# memory leak with images

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am trying to fix this memory problem in my codebase. I am using an ImageManager to keep track of all the allocations yet some of them are escaping my grasp. This are the leak suspects, but I cannot trace them or know how to interpret the leak suspect window.

[image: Leaking]

Comment: those  are the images in `/res/drawable` as well as system resource images, should be no issue since there is tricky shared memory magic involved so it's not actually 8mb

Comment: But the application is shown in all the memory managers, debugger and stack as ~16M big, 12 of which are byte[] allocations.

Comment: See http://jaxenter.com/android-dalvik-virtual-machine-35498.html the Zygote part. The way I understand it is: Android's system resources (button images, strings, the android framework library .jar etc) are not actually loaded multiple times into memory but shared between apps, yet the memory is listed as if it would belong to them. Anyways, everything under `android.content.res.Resources` is not a leak, just the resources that are required to run your app.

Comment: Well, you were right. Memory consumption in low-end devices is far far smaller. With other tweaks I could get it to just a couple of megs :D