# Android.Content.Res.Resources keeps in Memory from start

Tags: android, memory

I am investigating my Memory consumption of my app using DDMS Heap dumps and I detect memory consumption from android.content.res.Resources, that I do not understand :

```
The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 2.789.728 (12,92%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
java.lang.Object[]
android.content.res.Resources
```

I have 95 Pictures in my res/drawable with an overall size of 1.5 Mb. I do not use all of them at start. Are they loaded into memory from start and kept in memory ?

Answer (score 0):

As it's written in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255212/memory-leak-with-images) question, you dont need to worry about this memory since Android manages them wisely and its not considered a memory leak.

Comment: I also guess I don't have to care and I know this is no memory leak. But I try to understand if the resources are all loaded from start insteed of not using it. So in memory consumption aspect, should I delete not used resources in my res folder.